# How to Deploy a website to Windows Azure with Sql server Compact file in App_data in VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-storage

I need a help to Deploy my Website on Windows Azure. I have a Database CodeCamper.sdf file in my App_data folder which is working good but i do not know how to deploy that application in Windows Azure and what will be my Connectionstring in that case. Currently i have no connectionstring in my web.config file. Here is my code

```
public CodeCamperDbContext()
        : base(nameOrConnectionString: "CodeCamper") { }

    static CodeCamperDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CodeCamperDbContext>(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure that the data files have their "[Copy to output directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)" property set to something other than "Never".

Here's [How to Deploy an Azure Website](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/)

Based on this article (below), it doesn't sound like you need to change anything in the web.config.

[Using SQL Server Compact for ASP.NET Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257(v=vs.110).aspx)